# Vue: changing the :root css variable that is used by child component: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mestorf-w1lsob?file=/src/App.vue

I have two simple files that result in a circle being displayed:

[image]

I'm trying to make the circle `div` non-round (change its width to another value) if the text inside the circle has more than one character (an example in plain css and js of what I'm trying to achieve: https://codepen.io/sabeser/pen/BaqBwga)

**Circle.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div class="circle">
    <span>{{ value }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.circle {
  background-color: var(--circle-background-color);
  width: var(--circle-width);
  height: var(--circle-height);

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  border-radius: 20em;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Circle",

  props: {
    value: String,
  },

  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Circle :value="this.text" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Circle from "./Circle.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Circle: Circle,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      text: "a",
    };
  },

  created() {
    if (this.text.length > 1) {
      this.root.style.setProperty("--circle-background-color", "blue");
      this.root.style.setProperty("--circle-width", "2vw");
      this.root.style.setProperty("--circle-height", "2vw");
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
:root {
  --circle-background-color: red;
  --circle-width: 4vw;
  --circle-height: 4vw;
}

#app {
}
</style>
```

However I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
```

error.

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid changing styles through Javascript in Vue, since the framework offers more native ways to handle it.

The default way would be to use `:style` bindings:

```html
<div class="circle" :style="{'--circle-width': value.length * 5 + 'vh'}">
  <span>{{ value }}</span>
</div>
```

or:

```html
<script>
export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    circleStyle(){
      return {
        '--circle-width': this.value.length * 5 + 'vh'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="circle" :style="circleStyle">
   ...
</template>
```

Or, in Vue 3 SFCs, you can use `v-bind` within `<style>`:

```html
<script>
const text = ref('a')
const width = computed(() => text.value.length * 5 + 'px')
</script>

<style>
.circle {
  --circle-width: v-bind(width);
}
</style>
```

Also note that for changing width depending on content, you might be better off with a pure CSS solution, as length of a string does not give reliable information about its width when printed (i.e. 'mmm' vs 'iii').

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Also have a look at the [CSS solution](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9VE1vEzEQ/SujrVBbqdukraiQGyoQHOAMEhdfnPUkMXhty+tNE6L8d8b2fkW0uez64817nplnH4rPzt1uWyxYsQhYOy0CPnMDsJBqmwY0/KJ8pRHYVugWP/Ii4C7wAmYZOOuRfRg0Ya8jrhZ+rUwZrGNwd+92T7zoKH8SA4OFMq4NsC1rK1EPxG/RVlo0TaRFqUS5USZip7jFbJICTZvKKxdorGpnfYAuj5W3NfDidpbnMX1ePMUI3CWcxJVodYBDpDWiRkZwKhQvbuJKZYnOoAkNyxDomFn3T6gjfeNfiiCurnugx9B6088AYsaR/RtqbeGX9Vp2KsRAZ8o8cbSYDenE1GKJ0xDgdixIx5sL3xc9LVVWW8/g4uHh4Snz9rWdhLMlrqzHjqWyJlCWDC6/m8qjaDAtCWXQQ6P+Ioil3SJ8mM/dDigQnNIamo1weDlIfEr0cPWiZNjAc0ZfdxJvak/Vv+Lr6kvU9mWiXuX2jvrdCehDxUsFK26Ksemveh6UJIsNSoNjT/foYMMOwOEA6WrAMelNzXvWnn0Pw8WYWZe/VA0h9wyU0bRerjTmTvLwu22CWu3LoUAVfdFHAwcehFZrUypSIncOO8TIw1JUf9betkZSbHIDGapurDm1yMuGorulpfUSfemFVC3x3c+x7nZqutippQweqQG9pU6zYWJF+iklHvrz8iLdttGn6YG4m8/fnfoy0VBALgkPTkipzJrBHO4eR8UMPuuy/8sLMGF7n4VHt4x+OX1Gzj0P2Vbp7sZl560bn4fkDgY/gifJ4XU4udXF8R/4zNSV) (not sure if this is what you want to achieve though).

Comment: How do I make it work with `@media` queries though?

Comment: I tried to make use of style object in `computed`, this is a simplified example: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-violet-r6jlhy?file=/src/Circle.vue

As can be seen, it doesn't work: the circle is not red, its width is not '50px'

Comment: Could you make your ` computed: { circleStyle(){` example into a `codesandbox`? Because it simply doesn't work neither in my project, not in simplified example I linked above

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `circleStyle` object correctly? The point of my post is making use of global variables (so that the media quries would get automatically updated with correct width too).

Comment: Oh, in your sandbox, you set the attribute with `style="circleStyle"`, but you have to bind it with `:style="circleStyle"` (with a `:`). Have a look at the playground link I added to the answer. But I don't fully understand what you are asking for with the `@media` queries - you cannot use those in inline styles or javascript, but that might just be another question. Anyway, if you add the `:`, does it work?

Comment: Thank you for the playground link! Is there any reason for the `created() {if (this.text.length > 1) {` code? Or it can be removed? When it comes to `@media`, currently my circles have a bigger width on small screens. The values are currently hardcoded in `@media` styles. However if the circle has several letters, I need them to be oval, including on small screens... so `@media` can no longer be hardcoded

Comment: I think I figured out the `@media` part - I created several `--circle-width` variables, each for a specific screen size, use them in `@media` quieries and update them inside the `computed` part! Thank you, your answer and the playground helped a lot! I find it interesting, how changing the seemingly global `--circle-width` variable only makes the change apply to a specific circle!

Comment: That's great! I agree, those CSS variables are real game changers. I'll probably use them more in the future, too. I have added another playground link, where width and height of the circle/pill is set depending on text width through CSS only. Not sure if it helps though. Anyway, this was fun!

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a reference for your current vue component. You can use [ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) for Dom operations:

```js
<template>
  <div ref="circle">
    <Circle :value="this.text" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Circle from "./Circle.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Circle: Circle,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      text: "a",
    };
  },

  created() {},
  mounted() {
    if (this.text.length > 1) {
      this.$refs.circle.style.setProperty("--circle-background-color", "blue");
      this.$refs.circle.style.setProperty("--circle-width", "2vw");
      this.$refs.circle.style.setProperty("--circle-height", "2vw");
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
:root {
  --circle-background-color: red;
  --circle-width: 4vw;
  --circle-height: 4vw;
}

#app {
}
</style>
```

Comment: It works, but if I have several `Circle` objects, it would make them all blue&wide, even those that have only one letter inside. Is there a way to go around that? I've been using global variables, because later my media queries can use those variables to change circle width depending on screen size...